# .format() and list indexing methods

Tags: python

Considering the following flowers and colors lists, write the program using .format() and list indexing methods that will print out the text below.

```
text = "My two favorite flowers are tulip and rose, two favorite colors are blue and green." 
flowers = [["jasmine", ["lavender", "rose"], "tulip"]]
colors = ["red", ("blue", ["yellow", "green"]), "pink"]

print("My two favorite flowers are {} and {}, two favorite colors are {} and {} ".format(, , , ))
```

thats where I'm stuck

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why is arguments to `.format` empty? did you go over the documentation for it yet?

Comment: Also, why not use f-strings in Python 3.6+?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
print("My two favorite flowers are {} and {}, two favorite colors are {} and {} ".format(flowers[0][-1], flowers[0][-2][-1], colors[1][0], colors[1][1][1]))
```

I am assuming you know list indexing but having problem with `.format()` and placeholders. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) for a beginning reference on this topic.

Comment: i know list indexing but thats giving error i try that too
pls look at the error : https://prnt.sc/1wjdbsv

Comment: See, I have mentioned that there are extra brackets in `flowers` list and so indexing would change. I have updated my answer for the same and it should work fine now.

Comment: ok ty so much i need to work more

Comment: I am guessing it worked. Also practice more and try to do these by yourself, It will help you learn a lot about things in general.

Comment: It is just to let you know that you can find answers to these questions by minimal research, reading docs or a well defined google search. So, it would be better if you come with good questions next time.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. you need to explain what your problem is, and what you have tried. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask